# Django projects with Postgres stopped working after brew install

Tags: python, django, postgresql, homebrew, pipenv

I was trying to get [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to work, and so followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path) to `brew install geckodriver` in the relevant virtual environment (pipenv). After having done that, my other virtual environments stopped working.

I was able to get most of them to work again by re-installing pipenv outside of any virtual environment (using `pip3 install pipenv`).

But all of my Django projects that rely on Postgres still don't work: I'm able to start their virtual environment (with `pipenv shell`), but `python manage.py runserver` gives me the following traceback:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'admin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/my_last_name/Django/pred_market_pg_copy/pm_project/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('mp/', admin.site.urls),
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 529, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "/Users/my_last_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/pred_market_pg_copy-ZXHemaJW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

I have `'django.contrib.admin'` among my `INSTALLED_APPS`. And, again, everything was working just fine prior to my geckodriver adventure.

Re-installing psycopg2 with `pipenv install psycopg2` doesn't solve it. I've also tried uninstalling psycopg2, but when I then try to install it again, I get `Locking Failed`.

Any advice here on what's going on would be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably easier to run postgres from docker than manage all the dependencies on your local system.

Comment: @monkut thanks, you might be right. Does that offer a way to “recover” the projects I currently have that are no longer working?

Comment: If you can't access the db independently from your application to dump data, probably not.

Comment: Ignore the Docker advice that is just another set of things that can go wrong. If you don't believe me search SO for docker postgresql  django. Have you tried to uninstall ```geckodriver```? The issue seems to be ```Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib``` which looks like psycopg2 is reaching outside virtualenv. Try uninstalling psycopg2 and then install psycopg2-binary.

Comment: The project code is still there and can be moved to another virtualenv if need be. I doubt very much if anything is wrong with the database and if Django could reach it then you can also. In that case you can retrieve the data if necessary, though I don't think that will need to happen.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver many thanks - I was able to get it to work along the lines you're suggesting. Ended up creating a new virtual environment and installing Django and all other dependencies, before copying the code from the old environment there (except for the old `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files). This worked, but only if I first did `pipenv install psycopg2` and then followed that with `pipenv install psycopg2-binary` - not sure why, but at least it's all up and running again now.